# How to move iboutlets with auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Currently I am having a extremely annoying problem with auto layout. In my code this piece of code is not working.

```
Poop.center = CGPointMake(enemyPosition, -40);
```

I need to use auto layout because of resizing my app to all kinds of phones. It seems whenever I try to use a certain piece of code that moves a object, instead of moving it the the x and y point I want it to move to it moves back to the original position in the view controller.

this is my position enemy

```
 -(void)positionEnemy {
// Random enemy position
enemyPosition = arc4random() % 249;
enemyPosition = enemyPosition + 20;
// Set enemy Image location
Poop.center = CGPointMake(enemyPosition, -40);

// Set enemy speed
randomSpeed = speedOfEnemy;

enemyAttackOccurence = arc4random() % 1;

[self performSelector:@selector(enemyMovementTimerMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:enemyAttackOccurence];
[self performSelector:@selector(addscoreMethod)];
[self harderGame];


}
```

and I call positionEnemy at the end of my other void

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Poop.frame, toilet.frame)){
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/plop.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error2;
    Plop = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url2 error:&error2];
    Plop.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [Plop play];

    [self addfive];
    [enemyMovementTimer invalidate];
    [self positionEnemy];

}
```

(in case your wondering the void add five in my code is where I set up my score). This problem is associated with auto layout because when I go into my storyboard and click disable auto layout everything works perfectly.
 This problem has been killing me and help would definentally be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using auto layout then you probably have some constraints in your storyboard. Just make outlets for them and modify `constant` property from the code. The key idea is that in auto layout you should not modify frames directly but constraints. In your case adding `constraint` that pin the center will be enough

Comment: Yes. Please check that my [demo project](https://github.com/Azat92/AutolayoutDemo) at GitHub